# Configure Server Timeout for Incoming HTTP Requests on a Micronaut Server

Tags: http, timeout, micronaut

I need to configure my server to time out incoming requests if no response is able to be returned after 20 seconds.

I've tried several of the yaml configuration properties listed in the micronaut documentation [here](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-core/latest/guide/configurationreference.html). No matter what property I use the server doesn't appear to enforce the timeout.

Currently my application.yaml file looks like this while I am debugging, as you can see I'm trying many properties at once but individually I was also running into the same issue.

```
micronaut:
  http:
    client:
      read-timeout: 1ms
      read-idle-timeout: 1ms
  application:
    name: oai-market-api
  server:
    port: ${PORT:8080}
    read-timeout: 1
    read-idle-timeout: 1ms
    idle-timeout: 1ms
    cors:
      enabled: true
```

The controller I am testing looks like this

```
@Controller("market-status")
public class MarketStatusController {

    public MarketStatusController() {}

    @Get
    public String getMarketStatus() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return "foo";
    }

}
```

The problem is that no matter what property I use for the timeout configurations, my app doesn't appear to enforce the response timeout and I still get responses that exceeded the timeout I am trying to use. I've tried many different properties but still no enforcement.

What is the correct config value for this use case? Am I missing anything else?

Comment: I haven't had much time to investigate this but just FYI server.read-timeout does not nothing according to https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/server/HttpServerConfiguration.html#getReadTimeout()

Comment: Did you try https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/server/HttpServerConfiguration.html#setWriteIdleTimeout(java.time.Duration) ?

Comment: @saw303 I tried the equivalent yaml property micronaut.server.write-idle-timeout but still no enforcement. Should I be using HttpServerConfiguration as a bean?

Comment: no, I was just referring to the javadocs since I couldn’t find it in the docs. Use the yaml property, thats the way to go in general

Comment: Is there some possibility that these configuration values are not being injected properly?

Comment: The issue is here

      server:
       port: ${PORT:8080}
       read-timeout: 1

The timeout property above is in minutes. Perhaps thats zhe issue that is limiting you to drop connection. since its integer one cant use something like 0.001. Open an issue or MR on their github I guess.